# Conflito de Múltiplos CSS's

Tags: css, bootstrap-datepicker

Olá,

Estou fazendo uma tabela HTML e estou usando minha folha de estilo.CSS, porém recentemente fiz um datepicker com o bootstrap e o link do estilo deles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Porém ela está modificando minha table, como eu faria para esse link do css do bootstrap "Trabalhasse" apenas no datepicker ?

Abraço.

Comment: Vc é novo no site então vou te dar uma dica, sempre que for realizar alguma pergunta no site, procure sempre inserir os códigos relevantes a pergunta, no seu caso o html e o Css. Voltando a questão, os estilos do Bootstrap só interferem sobre sua tabela se vc colocar alguma classe do bootstrap nela.

Answer (score 1):

Como sua aplicação está utilizando seu style personalizado e o Bootstrap. Provavelmente está usando classes com o mesmo nome, logo o bootstrap irá ter maior nível de prioridade, por conta dos atributos !important nas classes do Bootstrap. Logo ele terá maior prioridade na hora da construção do layout.

Aconselho que altere o nome da sua classe, que está na sua folha de estilo customizada e acionando o !important, logo a frente da formatação CSS de sua tabela.